# Create Ruby array from JSON in Middleman

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, middleman

I would like to create a Ruby array of numbers in Middleman from a JSON file that I'm using for local data. The purpose is to use various methods to compare and add values. I'm so close, but I can't figure out how to get the loop contents into an array.

I've read some related questions and docs, but syntax-wise I'm not sure where Middleman begins and ends in regards to JSON.

With the example below, I'd hope to generate a Ruby array such as:
    max_bet = [4,8]

A small sample of JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "wins": 10,
    "totalSpins": 16,
    "maxBet": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "wins": 10,
    "totalSpins": 21,
    "maxBet": 8
  }
]
```

To achieve the end result manually, I'm outputting the result of a loop and then pasting that into an array manually.

```
def maxBet
  all = [4,8]
  all.max
end
```

The final attempt I made at simulating what I want to create was printing an invalid array. It seems like I need to iterate with a for loop and push the results into an array, but I can't figure out how.

```
\[
- data.roulettingale.each do |s|
  =s.maxBet
\,
\]

[4,8,]
```

I would greatly appreciate help in how to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either I did not understand your question, or:

```
s = '[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "wins": 10,
    "totalSpins": 16,
    "maxBet": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "wins": 10,
    "totalSpins": 21,
    "maxBet": 8
  }
]'
require 'json'
JSON.parse s
#⇒ [
#   {"id"=>"001", "wins"=>10, "totalSpins"=>16, "maxBet"=>4},
#   {"id"=>"002", "wins"=>10, "totalSpins"=>21, "maxBet"=>8}
# ]
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD** To produce an array, containing `maxBet`s:

```
data.roulettingale.map { |item| 
  item['maxBet'] 
}
#⇒ => [
#  [0] 4,
#  [1] 8
# ]

data.roulettingale.map { |item| 
  item['maxBet'] 
}.inspect
#⇒ [4, 8]
```

To select the maximal value of the `maxBet`:

```
data.roulettingale.map { |item| 
  item['maxBet'] 
}.max
#⇒ 8
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking a peek at it. I don't think I was clear on what I'm trying to do so I edited my question. Luckily with Middleman, I get parsing built-in. My dream scenario is to get an end result of just the numbers from all objects. Like:
    m = [4,8]

Comment: So, your `data.roulettingale` contains this json and you want to print out maximal `maxBet`, right?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I was coming back in to update because I got some help on Twitter, but this is it!